# how can ı access all inputs in form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I found this code in https://codepen.io/pkbhuiyan/pen/VaVNQd . I passed "id" to form tag and I am trying to access all inputs in form tag but it does not work.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(function ($) {
    var $inputs = $( "#contact_form :input" ).prop("disabled", true);;

    $("#edit_btn").click(function () {
      $("#submit_btn").show(0);
      $("#edit_btn").hide(0);
      $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
      $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
      $("#submit_btn").hide(0);
      $("#edit_btn").show(0);
    });

  });

});
```

HTML:

```
      <div id="kursiyerprofili"> 
        <form action="/" method="post">
          <div class="main">
              <div class="container-fluid">

                  
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="contact_form col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                          <form name="contact_form" id="contact_form" class="contact_form" method="post">
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                                      <label>İSİM</label>
                                      <input name="name" id="student-name" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                                      <label>SOYİSİM</label>
                                      <input name="surname" id="student-surname" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
                                  </div>

                                  
                                  <div class=" pull-right profile-edit-button ">
                              
                                    <a id="edit_btn" class="btn btn-warning" name="submit">Profili Düzenle</a>
                                    <a id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-warning" name="submit">Değişiklikleri Kaydet</a>
                                    <!--<span id="notice" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable hidden" style="margin-left:20px;"></span>-->
                                   </div>


                              </div>
                              
                              
                          </form>
                      </div> <!--contact-form-->
                  </div> <!--row-->
              </div> <!--container-fluid-->
          </div> <!--main-->
        </form>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If my form is like below:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php"></form>
```

I can access all elements like bwlow:

```
 document.getElementById("myForm").elements
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way:

```
$("form").each(function(){
    $(this).find(':input') 
});
```